# Link to a dynamic route, as defined in a controller property

Tags: ember.js

Since I have a bunch of different kind of objects which are very similar, in order to reuse templates / controllers / views, I am trying to define a template which links to a route as configured in the controller, something like this:

```
    <div class="form-actions">
        {{#linkTo newRoute class="btn btn-primary"}}<i class="icon-plus"></i> Add {{singularHuman}}{{/linkTo}}
    </div>
```

The controller is then:

```
App.NodesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    ...
    newRoute        : 'nodes.new',
    ...
});
```

But I am hitting the error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: The attempt to linkTo route 'newRoute' failed.
```

Is it at all possible to use `linkTo` with a "dynamic" target (in the sense, that it is setup in the controller)?

Comment: Property lookup for linkTo will work after this commit ( https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/5c3b035ec407974edc37fbb378ba8250dba8dded )

Comment: it hasnt been in the release build yet !!!

Comment: Ooops. It looks I am living on the edge. For a newbie, not really good! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PR](https://github.com/machty/ember.js/commit/9ddb8eec4c8dd48cd06a421e57b765dceecc962d) mentioned in the comments is already in ember-latest but must be explicitly enabled with `ENV.HELPER_PARAM_LOOKUPS = true`.

To use this new behaviour just set the `ENV.HELPER_PARAM_LOOKUPS` before your ember.js is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    ENV.HELPER_PARAM_LOOKUPS = true;
</script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-latest.js"></script>
...
```

Comment: It is in the repo, but it has not yet made it to the starter kit or any of the release channels. Unfortunately I am unable to build ember on my system.

Comment: @gonvaled, yes this is true, but if you want you can get the latest releases always from here: http://builds.emberjs.com/ since it's the original release channel